# First input autofocus for OTP input fields in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I made OTP input in React [You can see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrEHK.png). One line is one input and I have 6 inputs. The inputs work that is not a problem. I need when the component opens, the first input must be autofocus. When I use `<input autofocus/>` the last input is autofocus, I need the first input.

My parent component

```
  const [code, setcode] = useState(new Array(6).fill(""));
```

OTP component

```
 <div className="digit-inputs">
        {props.code.map((data, index) => {
          return (
            <input
              disabled={props.second <= 0 ? true : false}
              type="text"
              className="otp-field"
              name="otp"
              maxLength={1}
              key={index}
              style={data ? { borderBottom: "3px solid #7dbf2a" } : { borderBottom: "3px solid grey" }}
              value={data}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target, index)}
              onFocus={(e) => e.target.select}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
```

My function

```
  const handleChange = (element, index) => {
    if (isNaN(element.value)) return false;

    props.setcode([...props.code.map((d, indx) => (indx === index ? element.value : d))]);

    //Focus next input

    if (element.nextSibling) {
      element.nextSibling.focus();
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just wanted the focus when the component mounts, you can use the index of the array. just add `autoFocus={index === 0}`.

```
         <input
          type="text"
          className="otp-field"
          name="otp"
          maxLength={1}
          key={index}
          style={
            data
              ? { borderBottom: "3px solid #7dbf2a" }
              : { borderBottom: "3px solid grey" }
          }
          //value={data}
          onFocus={(e) => e.target.select}
          autoFocus={index === 0} // add this line
          //onChange
        />
```

Comment: i tried this but keyboard autofocus is not working

Comment: <TextInput
                  autuFocus={true}ref={textInputRef}
                  placeholder="0"
                  placeholderTextColor="black"
                  keyboardBehavior="extend"
                  keyboardType="decimal-pad"
                  maxLength={8}
                  onChangeText={text => {
                   
                  }}
                />

Comment: @Vishali can you make a code sandbox for your code?